# Const behavior in operator >>

Tags: c++, constants

Let's consider the following code (live at: http://ideone.com/3Ky4Kr)

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <cstdlib>
#include <cstring>

class StrStrTest {
public:
    StrStrTest(const std::string& ba) {
        a = (char*)calloc(1, ba.length() + 1);
        strcpy(a, ba.c_str());
    }
    virtual ~StrStrTest() {
        free(a);
    }
private:
    char* a;
    friend std::basic_ostream<char>& operator << (std::basic_ostream<char>& ss, const StrStrTest& a);
    friend std::basic_istream<char>& operator >> (std::basic_istream<char>& ss,const StrStrTest& a);
};
std::basic_ostream<char>& operator << (std::basic_ostream<char>& ss, const StrStrTest& a) {
    ss << a.a;
    return ss;
}
std::basic_istream<char>& operator >> (std::basic_istream<char>& ss,
                                       const StrStrTest& a) {
    ss >> a.a;  // <<-- HERE
//    a.a = NULL;
    return ss;
}
int main()
{
    StrStrTest bb("foo");
    std::cin >> bb;
    std::cout << bb;
}
```

Firstly, why does it compile? On the line marked with **<<-- HERE** I (subtly) modify a `const` object. (obviously `a.a = NULL;` does not compile, that's too obvious).

Secondly does this lead to undefined behaviour?

PS: Please don't consider that the code is not safe, might overwrite memory it does not own, `char*` vs. `std::string`, etc... I know these, and it is not the point of the question, this is not production code.

Comment: The memory you modify is allocated on the heap and just happens to also be pointed to by a const object.

Answer (score 4):

The overload you are using is this: `operator>>(std::istream&, char*)`. It takes a `char*`, by value. It doesn't modify the pointer (i.e. It doesn't change the pointer to point somewhere else). It modifies the data which the pointer holds the address of, writing a null terminated c-string to that location. So, the const-ness of your object is not being violated, because that data is not part of your object.

If you try to do something like this:

```
a.a = NULL;
```

That *is* modifying a member of your object, and so is not allowed.

> Secondly does this lead to undefined behaviour?

It can, if `a.a` does not point to properly allocated memory with enough space for the next space delimited char data in the stream. But not as a result of anything to do with the const-ness of the `StrStrTest` object.